# add_library is not creating a .lib with c sources

Tags: c++, c, cmake, bcrypt

I'm trying to use the c wrapper around the crypt blowfish project, from library https://github.com/trusch/libbcrypt also with a cpp wrapper around the two files bcrypt.c and bcrypt.h. I create a bcryptcpp.lib from the sources but when using them with an executable I get undefined symbol errors.
Here's my cmakelists.txt -

```
# BCrypt CPP
enable_language(ASM)

set(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "${CXXFLAGS} -x assembler-with-cpp")

include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/crypt_blowfish-1.3)

set(BCRYPT_SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/BCrypt.hpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/BCrypt.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/WinBCrypt.hpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bcrypt.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bcrypt.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/crypt_blowfish-1.3/crypt_blowfish.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/crypt_blowfish-1.3/crypt_blowfish.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/crypt_blowfish-1.3/crypt_gensalt.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/crypt_blowfish-1.3/crypt_gensalt.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/crypt_blowfish-1.3/wrapper.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/crypt_blowfish-1.3/x86.S
)

add_library(bcryptcpp
    STATIC
        ${BCRYPT_SOURCES})

set_target_properties(bcryptcpp
    PROPERTIES
        VERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION}"
        PUBLIC_HEADER BCrypt.hpp
        LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
        FOLDER "BCrypt"
)
```

The bcryptcpp.lib that is generated by visual studio is only 2kb. Would it be that the c files aren't compiled? What could be the issue here?

The errors are as follows, generated when compiling a test executable which includes only the 3 headers in the library link mentioned above (BCrypt.hpp, BCrypt.cpp, winbcrypt.h) -

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 3 unresolved externals  BCryptTest  C:\Program Files (x86)\Horizon\test\Debug\BCryptTest.exe    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _bcrypt_gensalt referenced in function "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl BCrypt::generateHash(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?generateHash@BCrypt@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV23@H@Z)    BCryptTest  C:\Users\sagun\horizon-cpp\build\src\Tests\BCryptTest.obj   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _bcrypt_hashpw referenced in function "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl BCrypt::generateHash(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?generateHash@BCrypt@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV23@H@Z) BCryptTest  C:\Users\sagun\horizon-cpp\build\src\Tests\BCryptTest.obj   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _bcrypt_checkpw referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl BCrypt::validate_password(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?validate_password@BCrypt@@SA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) BCryptTest  C:\Users\sagun\horizon-cpp\build\src\Tests\BCryptTest.obj   1
```

The output of `dumpbin /EXPORTS bcryptcpp.lib` shows no exports, so I'm guessing its wrongly compiled -

```
Dump of file bcryptcpp.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

  Summary

          20 .chks64
         43C .debug$S
          74 .debug$T
          30 .drectve
```

Comment: `enable_language(ASM)` enables only assembler. Do you have a `project()` call, which, by default, enables C and C++ languages? Why do you think that the library of size 2KB is too small for 6 source files? "when using them with an executable I get undefined symbol errors" - Add these errors into the question post. Without that we can only guess what is wrong.

Comment: sorry, added to the question. Also yes I have a project() which includes c, c++. this cmake file is just an inclusion. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For understanding a reason of problem (*CMakeLists.txt* or *bad linking in another project*) You need to check your **.lib** file.
Try to find export symbols in **bcryptcpp.lib** via [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-command-line?view=vs-2017).
Open a visual command console and run the next command:

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS bcryptcpp.lib
```

If you will see your functions under the **exports** header it means your library is right compiled and you need to check a library architecture (**x86**, **x64**) - maybe you link a wrong library to your another project.

In another case, the problem in *CMakeLists.txt*.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've edited the question with the output of the command. There are no export symbols.

Comment: **bcryptcpp.lib** doesn't have export symbols. Could you share your project?